# clock();関数を使ってミリ秒を利用したフレームレートを制御の仕方が知りたい。待機するミリ秒を得たい。

Tags: c++, opengl

提示コードのvoid Wait();関数部ですがwaitTime変数の値を表示させたのですが常にマイナスの値が出力されてしまい待機してくれません。なぜ待機してくれなのでしょか？待機できな程の負荷がかかってるとは到底思えないコードのため必ずこの数字はプラスの値が来ると思われるのですがなぜなのでしょうか？

確認したこと
変数はすべてコンストラクタ部で初期化０の値

```
#define FRAME_RATE 60
```

参考サイト: https://dixq.net/g/03_14.html
※ clock();関数はミリ秒を返す関数です。

追記clock()関数はCPU時間を返すの間違えていますよって以下のうにglfwGetTime()関数を使って秒をdouble型で取得してそれに1000掛けることによってミリ秒を取得しています。よって下の提示コードのclock();関数部は以下の関数に書き換えましたが
矩形を描画して移動させていましたがなんか突っかかる感じがするのでまだ間違えています。

```
int getTime()
{
    return (int)(glfwGetTime() * 1000.0f);
}
```

利用ライブラリ
glew
glfw
opengl
stb　関係ありません
glm　関係ありません
freeType　関係ありません

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

```
// ##################################### 待機フレームを計算 ##################################### 
void FrameWork::Window::FrameUpdate(glm::vec4 color)
{
    float c = 1.0f / 255.0f;
    glClearColor(color.x * c, color.y * c, color.z * c, color.w * c);                                   //カラーバッファのクリア色
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT | GL_STENCIL_BUFFER_BIT | GL_ACCUM_BUFFER_BIT);   //フレームバッファを初期化

    glEnable(GL_BLEND); //アルファブレンド有効
    glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);  //ブレンドタイプ

    //フレームレートを制御する

    if (count == 0)
    {
        startCount = (int)clock();
    }

    if (count == FRAME_RATE)
    {
        startCount = (int)clock();
        count = 0;
    }

    count++;
}

// ##################################### フレームを取得 ##################################### 
int FrameWork::Window::getFrame()
{
    return count;
}

// ##################################### フレームレート　待機 ##################################### 
void FrameWork::Window::Wait()
{
    int tookTime = clock() - startCount;
    int waitTime = (count * 1000 / FRAME_RATE) - tookTime;


    std::cout << waitTime << std::endl;

    if (waitTime > 0)
    {
        //std::cout << waitTime << std::endl;

        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(waitTime));
    }
}
```

Comment: なぜ `clock()` を使っているのでしょう？ `clock()` は実時間ではなく CPU time を返すのですが。。。

Comment: なるほど。clock();関数の部分を以下のうにしたのですが矩形を描画して動かしてみるとなんか突っかかったような挙動になるのですがこの関数に問題があるのでしょうか？int getTime()
{
 return (int)(glfwGetTime() * 1000.0f);
}

Comment: そうなのですが値を確認すると0.1 1.0などをdouble 型なので1000かけるとミリ秒が取得できるという原理なのですがおかしいのでしょうか？

Comment: すみません、読み間違えていました。glfwGetTime() に関して、質問文に追記する方が良いかと思います。

Comment: 提示された情報だけでは、`count`の初期値が何時何処で設定されるのか？ `FRAME_RATE`の値は何か？ `FrameUpdate()`が何時何処から呼ばれるか？ それから`FrameUpdate()`,`getFrame()`,`Wait()`の間の関連性は何か？ といったことが不明です。何らかの原因で`FrameUpdate()`が呼ばれなくなって`count`が更新されないとか、あるいは何か別の関数が`count`を操作していて`FRAME_RATE`を飛び越えてしまい、リセットされなくなっているとかありませんか？

Comment: ちなみに参考サイトのDxLibによるプログラムでも、`waitTime`はずっとマイナス値で`Sleep()`は呼ばれないようですね。それでも周期的に数値は増減するので、それが1回行われただけのように見える質問のプログラムでは`FrameUpdate()`が呼ばれていないのか、`waitTime`が`-375`から`-32`になった時点で`count`が1回だけリセットされ、その後`count`をリセットする処理が何らかの原因で飛ばされたのかももしれません。

Comment: なるほど。FrameUpdate();はwhile();文の一番上でWait()関数は一番下に置いてるのですが。また変数もすべて０で初期化されてます。確認しました。

Comment: どうも`FRAME_RATE`を`60`ではなく`20`とか`10`とか小さい値にすると`waitTime`が1以上になりそうです。つまり画面の更新処理が`FRAME_RATE`の間隔以上に掛かっているのかもしれません。それから参考サイトでは`FrameUpdate()`の`if (count == FRAME_RATE)`は`FRAME_RATE`ではなく平均FPSを計算するためのサンプル数`N`なので別の数値です。一応`FRAME_RATE`と同じ数値でも動作するようですが。`FRAME_RATE`を変えるとか、`FrameUpdate()`のOpenGL関連処理をコメントアウトするとかして試してみてください。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 矩形を描画して移動させていましたがなんか突っかかる感じがするのでまだ間違えています。

回答ではないのですが、以下の環境で適当にプログラムを作成してみました(`FrameUpdate()` と `Wait()` メソッドと同等の関数を含みます)。

```sh
$ lsb_release -d
Description:    Ubuntu 21.04

$ apt-show-versions libglu1-mesa
libglu1-mesa:amd64/hirsute 9.0.1-1build1 uptodate

$ apt-show-versions libglfw3
libglfw3:amd64/hirsute 3.3.2-1 uptodate

$ apt-show-versions libglew-dev
libglew-dev:amd64/hirsute 2.1.0-4 uptodate

$ glmark2 --fullscreen --show-all-options
=======================================================
    glmark2 2021.02
=======================================================
    OpenGL Information
    GL_VENDOR:     Intel
    GL_RENDERER:   Mesa Intel(R) UHD Graphics 630 (CFL GT2)
    GL_VERSION:    4.6 (Compatibility Profile) Mesa 21.0.1
=======================================================
[build] duration=10.0:fps-pos=-1.0,-1.0:fps-size=0.03:fragment-precision=default,default,default,default:
interleave=false:model=horse:nframes=:show-fps=false:title=:title-pos=-0.7,-1.0:title-size=0.03:
use-vbo=false:vertex-precision=default,default,default,default: FPS: 1334 FrameTime: 0.750 ms
[build] duration=10.0:fps-pos=-1.0,-1.0:fps-size=0.03:fragment-precision=default,default,default,default:
interleave=false:model=horse:nframes=:show-fps=false:title=:title-pos=-0.7,-1.0:title-size=0.03:
use-vbo=true:vertex-precision=default,default,default,default: FPS: 1380 FrameTime: 0.725 ms
=======================================================
                                  glmark2 Score: 1357 
=======================================================
```

60 FPS では以下の様になります。こちらの環境では突っかかる感じは見受けられません。

[image: moving rectangle object]

`WaitTime` は 15ms 〜 17ms でした。また、参考までに 30 FPS, 70 FPS での結果も載せておきます。

```sh
$ ./moving_rectangle > record.dat

# 60 FPS
$ datamash --header-out min 1 max 1 mean 1 sstdev 1 < record.dat
 min  max     mean  sstdev
  15   17   16.317   0.636

# 30 FPS
$ datamash --header-out min 1 max 1 mean 1 sstdev 1 < record.dat
 min  max     mean  sstdev
  32   34   32.957   0.693

# 70 FPS
$ datamash --header-out min 1 max 1 mean 1 sstdev 1 < record.dat
 min  max     mean  sstdev
-150   14  -62.016  48.470
```

Comment: 何かしらのこちら側でも不具合として確認しました。別に調査することにしました。

Answer (score 2):

何が何でも`clock()`を使う必要があるのでしょうか？ 既に`<chrono>`を使われているようですので、[`std::chrono::steady_clock::now()`](https://ja.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/steady_clock/now)に切り替えることをお勧めします。
あわせて期間を指定する`sleep_for()`ではなく時刻を指定する[`std::this_thread::sleep_until()`](https://ja.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/sleep_until)に切り替えると更に簡単になります。

```
std::chrono::steady_clock::time_point startTime;
constexpr auto FrameInterval = 10ms;
```

としておけば

```
void FrameWork::Window::Wait() {
    std::this_thread::sleep_until(startTime + FrameInterval);
}
```

で済みませんか？

Comment: プログラム初心者なので値の動きが原理も確認したいのでclok();関数を使って行いのですが。よくない実装なのでしょうか？